# Can't access all extension methods for IApplicationBuilder outside of Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add an extension method for `IApplicationBuilder` and run `app.UseHsts()`, `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and `app.UseStaticFiles()`.

But I get an error when trying to run the different commands saying it can't find the method, but I have defined using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` which contains the extension methods.

For some reason I can't access the same extension methods in my IApplicationBuilder extension as in `Startup.cs`. I can access a few extension methods, but not all.

Code:

Startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

The extension:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCDefault(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    IHostingEnvironment env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

    app
        .UseSession(new SessionOptions() { IOTimeout = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0) })
        .UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    app.UseStaticFiles(); //causes an exception, method can't be found

    return app;
}
```

Comment: Add Namespace and use it.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. what namespace? the extensions should be in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder namespace

Comment: @TheRuler Are you sure you have a reference to *Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll* which has the `UseHsts` and `UseHttpsRedirection` extension?

Comment: `UseStaticFiles` is from the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll*. So make sure you are referencing the necessary dependencies

Comment: Are you referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (which should pull in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`?

Comment: Yes I'm referencing All. I now added nuget packages for HttpsPolicy and StaticFiles, but it didn't seem to change anything. can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. the packages are version 2.2.0-preview3-35497 but AspNetCore.All is 2.1.1. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I tried to downgrade the references to match the project, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

While they share the same namespace, they belong to different libraries.

Make sure that wherever that extension method is being defined that it has a reference to the necessary dependencies.

`UseHsts` and `UseHttpsRedirection` extensions are from *Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll*

`UseStaticFiles` is from *Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll*.